# Angular get - map inside map

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular7

I'm trying to call an API method inside map but the second API call is never being made. No console errors.

```
//This method is not being called - Not hitting the API method
this.getUserPermissions(localStorage.getItem('user_ref'));
```

Just wondering if I cannot call map inside map?

Below is my code.

```
  public isAuthenticated() {

    if (!this.loggedIn)
      this.redirectToLogin();

    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(`${this.settings.getApiSettings('uri')}/api/auth/IsTokenValid`, {
      params: { token: this.getToken }
    }).map( /// <<<=== use `map` here
      (response) => {

        if (response !== null) {

          var receivedToken = response["securityStamp"];
          var availableToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

           //Check if received a refreshed token. (tokens are refreshed every 15 minutes)
          if (receivedToken && receivedToken !== availableToken) {

            localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response["securityStamp"]);

          }

           this.user_permissions = this.getUserPermissions(localStorage.getItem('user_ref'));


        }

        let data = response;
        if (data == null)
          return false;
        else
          return true;

      }
    );

  }

  getUserPermissions(user_ref) {

    if (!this.loggedIn)
      this.redirectToLogin();

    const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { userRef: "44C4D2F7-76A0-4714-B8CA-3123F607AC5A" } as HttpParamsOptions;

    const httpOptions = {
      params: new HttpParams(httpParams),
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken
      })
    };

    return this.httpClient.get<Array<any>>(`${this.settings.getApiSettings('uri')}/api/auth/GetUserPermissions`, httpOptions).map( /// <<<=== use `map` here
      (response) => {

        if (response["status"] == 401) {
          this.redirectToLogin();
        }
        else if (response["status"] < 200 || response["status"] >= 300) {
          throw new Error('This request has failed ' + response["status"]);
        }

        this.user_permissions = response;
        return response;
      }
    );

  }
```

Comment: Are you really using Angular7 here? Because if you are, you shouldn't be directly able to use an RxJS operator like `.map` by chaining it to an `Observable` as you've done. Just making sure so that I could suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `.map()` function does not return a subscription but an observable.
If you need to interact with the response from the HttpClient's api call then you'll need to subscribe to the `.get()` or `.post()` method you're calling.

This might do what you need, or at least log it in the console in case the request fails.

```js
firstUrl = `${this.settings.getApiSettings('uri')}/api/auth/IsTokenValid`;
secondUrl = `${this.settings.getApiSettings('uri')}/api/auth/GetUserPermissions`;

public isAuthenticated() {

    if (!this.loggedIn) this.redirectToLogin();
    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(this.firstUrl, {params: {token: this.getToken}}).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            if (response !== null) {
                let receivedToken = response["securityStamp"];
                let availableToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
                if (receivedToken && receivedToken !== availableToken) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', response["securityStamp"]);
                }
                this.user_permissions = this.getUserPermissions(localStorage.getItem('user_ref'));
            }
            return response != null;
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}

getUserPermissions(user_ref) {
    if (!this.loggedIn) this.redirectToLogin();
    const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = {userRef: "44C4D2F7-76A0-4714-B8CA-3123F607AC5A"} as HttpParamsOptions;
    const httpOptions = {
        params: new HttpParams(httpParams),
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<any>>(this.secondUrl, httpOptions).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            if (response["status"] == 401) {
                this.redirectToLogin();
            } else if (response["status"] < 200 || response["status"] >= 300) {
                throw new Error('This request has failed ' + response["status"]);
            }
            this.user_permissions = response;
            return response;
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Angular (more importantly rxjs) are you using?

Remember that HttpClient returns and Observable (a lazy observable that will not do anything until you subscribe to it).

https://angular.io/guide/http

As your `isAuthenticated` method returns a HttpClient Get method, your `isAuthenticated` returns an observable waiting to be subscribed to.

Subscribing to the HttpClient observable will make make the http call, call the observers next handler when the response is received and also call the on complete handler if provided. I would recommend reading up on Observables here.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/

```
// Doing this will not do anything as the observable has not been subscribed to.
this.httpClient.get<boolean>(`...`);

// Subscribing to the HttpClient will make the request
this.httpClient.get<boolean>(`...`)
    .subscribe((response) => {

      // do something with the response

});
```

As you said the first HttpCall is made, i'm assuming you are subscribing to the `isAuthenticated` method when you are calling it? i.e.

```
isAuthenticated().subscribe( (response) => {
 //
})
```

Notice that your `getUserPermissions` also returns a HttpClient method (an observable), yet when you call it `this.getUserPermissions(localStorage.getItem('user_ref'));` it is never subscribed to, and hence never called.

To initiate that second request, you would have to subscribe to the `getUserPermissions` call, something like the below.

```
public isAuthenticated() {

    // ...

    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>('...').map(
      (response) => {

           // Subscribe to the second Http call

           this.getUserPermissions(localStorage.getItem('user_ref'))
             .subscribe( (response) => {
               // do something with the second
           })
       })
}
```

A couple of side notes;
The `map` operator you are chaining on to the `httpClient.get` method has been deprecated as of rxjs v6 in favour of the pipe operator.

see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

So this

```
this.httpClient.get<boolean>('...')
    .map( ... )
    .subscribe(...)
```

Should now be written like this:

```
this.httpClient.get<boolean>('...')
  .pipe(        // <- Pipe the operators
    map( ... ),
    map( ... )
  )
  .subscribe( ...)
```

Although outside of the original question, I would look at refactoring your code and use the rxjs/operators available for better flow control.

```
this.httpClient.get<boolean>('...')
    .pipe(       
      map(( response ) => {
        // some logic
        return something;
      }),
      map( (something) => localStorage.getItem('user_ref')),
      switchMap( (userRef) => this.getUserPermissions(userRef)), // <- switchMap to a new observable
    )
    .subscribe( (responseFromGetUserPermissions) => {
       // This value is now the return of getUserPermissions because of switchMap

    })
```

rxjs / observable are a really powerful pattern, I highly recommend spending a great deal of time learning how to get the most out of them.

Regards
Jono

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can call map within a map, but the problem here for which you are not invoking the API is because your method "getUserPermissions" is returning an Observable and not the user's data.

I recommend that you change the design of this part, following the reactive approach.

You can read this [link](https://medium.com/thecodinghype/reactive-programming-in-javascript-using-rxjs-3b05e186c115).

I hope this helps you